# Combinatorics of enumerating theta characteristics - a meaningless coincidence?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, co.combinatorics

A Riemann surface $X$ of genus $g$ has $2^{g-1}(2^g +1)$ theta characteristics (henceforth conflated with spin structures) of even parity, and $2^{g-1}(2^g-1)$ odd theta characteristics. These numbers can also be expressed as binomial coefficients: 
$$
2^{g-1}(2^g +1) = {2^g + 1 \choose 2},
$$
$$
2^{g-1}(2^g -1) = {2^g \choose 2}.
$$
**Is this a meaningless coincidence, or is there a way of identifying even/odd spin structures with $2$-element subsets of a set of the appropriate size? Is it possible to give an algebro-geometric interpretation of this set?**

The argument I know for the enumeration of spin structures of given parity is not especially enlightening: one chooses a symplectic basis for $H_1(X; \mathbb{Z}/2)$, and this gives rise to a basepoint $q_0$ (necessarily an even form) in the set of $\mathbb{Z}/2$-quadratic forms as the unique form taking the value $0$ on every element of the symplectic basis. Then any other $q$ is of the form $q = q_0 + \langle\cdot,\eta\rangle$ for some $\eta \in H_1(X, \mathbb{Z}/2)$ (and where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is the intersection pairing). Then one shows that the Arf invariant of $q$ can be defined as $\operatorname{Arf}(q) = q(\eta) = q_0(\eta)$. This means that the set of even/odd forms is identifiable with the preimage of $0$ (resp. $1$) of the map $q_0: H_1(X, \mathbb{Z}/2) \to \mathbb{Z}/2$, and one can show inductively that these sets have the required size. Unfortunately I don't see how these binomial coefficients might be lurking in this argument, and I certainly don't see how this points to an interpretation of a spin structure as a $2$-element subset of some natural set.

Comment: Maybe one way to make the study of theta characteristics more combinatorial is to look at the story for tropical curves/graphs as in this paper and ones it cites: https://arxiv.org/abs/1606.02282v1

Comment: Although I don't think subsets/binomial coefficients make any appearance in that paper...

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but you are probably aware that there is a nice combinatorial description of theta characteristics for hyperelliptic curves: they correspond to certain subset of the set of $2g+2$ Weierstrass points. From this you get easily the numbers of even and odd theta characteristics, though not in the form you ask.